How to check if a user is live on Instagram
Brief introduction: it is supposed to check whether the user is live on Instagram or not.
When I run it, it always says user is not live. No matter if the user is live or not live.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# username
username = '...'

# Construct the profile URL
url = f"https://www.instagram.com/{username}/"

# Retrieve the HTML page of the profile
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Find the live indicator element
live_indicator = soup.find('div', class_='hzyi9')

# Check if the user is live
if live_indicator:
    print(f"{username} is currently live!")
else:
    print(f"{username} is not live.")



Time for some debugging. Either step through the code in your IDE's debugger, or add print(...) statements to see what these variables have. You probably don't get the html you expect. print(response.text) should get you the details.

first check if page doesn't  use JavaScript to set some values - turn off JavaScript in browser and load page again. requests and beautifusoup can't run JavaScript and often it is the problem with modern pages. It may need to use Selenium to control real web browser which can run JavaScript

next check in browser if you can see status when you are not logged in - it may need to login with Selenium. You may also need to check if you can see status when you don't follow user. And you may check browser always use class hzyi9 because it may use different values for different users, different devices, or even different days.

instagram has API to get information in simpler way but sometimes APIs may not give access to all information (or it needs to pay for some information)
